# Retrieve the factory value with same ng-app name in two different html file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to play with angularjs. I have two html pages. Both the page got `ng-app` and the same ng-app name. Like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
```

Now I have written one java script file which defines the factory and also the two controllers for those two html pages. I have written one factory to share the data between those two pages. I am collecting the data from one page and trying to display the data in another html file.

In factory I have used get and set functions. And from the first controller I have set the values.

But when trying to get the same value in another page it's not displaying anything. Is it because the second html file `ng-app` is redefining everything ?
Is there any workaround to solve this problem with the same `ng-app` name ?

Comment: Each page is a separate app instance. So each has it's own factory instance. Would be much simpler to combine them into a *"single page application"* and use an angular router to switch between the internal page routes. Then you only have one app instance and factory is available across the whole app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `ng-app="app"` angular starts a new instance from your app. it is something like doing `new app()` in oop languages. so the new instance does not know anything about the first instance. Try to use the same instance and use routing to navigate between your pages.